# Using a apt repository to install packages but not auto-update them

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, dpkg

I had some problems with Linux, probably caused by a bug in the kernel or some drivers.
Old distriutions such as Ubuntu 12.10 work, and that's what I use.
However this release is old and isn't supported anymore, so I download most packages over the Debian repo web interface.
I want to add the Debian Jessie repository to *sources.list*, but I don't want to neither packages be upgraded automatically, nor over apt-get upgrade.
I want packages only be upgraded if I type: *apt-get install --only-upgrade packagename* or if it is required because *packagename* is required as an dependency by *apackageiwanttoinstall*.

Comment: add a  hold  line  in your apt conf  file  something  like   ' apt-get --hold {pkgs}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [APT Pinning](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences).  You should set the priority of Jessie packages low enough that they won't be auto-installed, e.g.

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=jessie
Pin-Priority: 50
```

See the `apt_preferences` man page.